# How to convert an .ai file to a .svg file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-format

I don't have a copy of Illustrator and cannot work with an `.ai` file I received. I've tried Inkscape and it won't work as the uniconverter is for 32-bit machines and it doesn't appear to read the `.ai` file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Download a trial](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator/free-trial-download.html).

Comment: @Joonas a trial lasts 7 days, a solution lasts a lifetime.

Comment: If you keep putting yourself in a situation where you need AI, maybe it's time to buy it?

Comment: if there is no alternative, agree.

Comment: Trial is a good idea for another reason, too. With it you can see does the real thing understand your ai file or not.

Answer (score 5):

Seemingly you have already tried inkscape. Skip the next and goto **"Other"**

**Inkscape** can import ai files to some degree. It at least works with simple drawings which do not contain unexpanded complex Ai's functions. Many Ai's functions have no replacement in SVG. Ai itself must expand or rasterize them before exporting as SVG.

Inkscape imports as expanded at least some Ai's functions which were in ai file still unexpanded. The following example shows that 3D extrusion, Warped text and Blend appear in Inkscape ok, but of course without a possiblity to adjust the effect.

[image]

The editable text isn't actually editable, it gets jumbled if you try. It can be copied and pasted to a new text object.

I have Win7x64 and Inkscape 0.92 portable.

Inkscape offers a possiblity to use some external (=not original Inkscape) import software library, but I have used default "internal" because it doesn't curve texts. You may still need to rewrite texts if you want to make edits. Fortunately they are copyable, you needn't retype all.

Both replace Ai's meshes with something which exist is SVG. It's told in the import starting dialog.

All shapes seem to be wrapped into multilevel groups, when you watch the structure of the result in the objects panel.

But they can be ungrouped. You want to do it If you make edits. It really is a big job when the drawing is complex. For full ungrouping there's Extensions > Arrange > Deep Ungroup.

Conclusion: It's not perfect, but it's free.

**Other:** If you search for "convert ai to svg" you find several online services. I haven't tried them. Read extremely carefully what you accept when you use them.

**Affinity Designer** opened my test ai. Ai's effects were of course expanded, but the structure was clear (=no grouping mess) and the editable text was still editable.

In a comment one suggests Ai trial. If that's still possible, it surely solve the problem for a short time. You can also rent full Adobe CC applications for limited time.

**BTW.** In Inkscape there's separated ai files fom Ai version 8 and earlier. Check, if you have here an error.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly open the .ai file with Acrobat and save as an EPS.. then convert to svg.

.ai files, by default, are also PDFs. That default can be changed, but maybe you'll get lucky.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work in this instance.